# bootstrap modal is shown in background

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to add modal to the HTML page, But unable to bring modal to the front, I've copied bootstrap sample code.

Also I tried to keep **JSFiddle**, Although it's working in **JSFiddle**, Not in my program.

So it's better to show the whole code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
 Launch demo modal
 </button>

 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
   <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
   ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

It should work like this but, in my code this type output will be produced...
[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPQP3.jpg)

Hope for help...

Comment: please provide more information for example your css, as it is most likely something you added in your css (z-index for example)

Comment: Pls, provide chunk of code as large as it could demonstrate the issue

Comment: (http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js),
I changed it to 
(http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js),

now it's working fine so i didn't need to change z-index or any CSS files.
@Banzay

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the default *z-index* value of 1040 for '`.modal-backdrop`' is being overridden by your custom CSS styles. Make sure the `z-index` for '.modal-backdrop' is set to **1040**.

Comment: I don't think that was the issue, I checked bootstrap.min.css & '.modal-backdrop' z-index value was 1040 only.
I don't know was the problem but **bootstap JS** file version solved my problem